# CREATE TABLE command keeps failing for a simple table with INT, FLOAT and VARCHAR

Tags: mysql

MySQL is extremely unhelpful when it comes to syntax errors. This command keeps failing for me:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, text VARCHAR(50), integer INT, floating FLOAT);
```

With an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near 'integer INT, floating FLOAT)' at line 1
```

It doesn't even tell me what's wrong. When I tried to google some syntax checker online, it gave me an error concerning different part of the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`integer` is a reserved word in MySQL which can't be used directly as a column name.

If you want to use it, you need to enclosed it with backticks, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                   text VARCHAR(50), `integer` INT, floating FLOAT);
```